# Preguntas abiertas

Tags: discusión

Como o donde se deberían publicar preguntas que mas que código es como es la mejor forma de hacer. Por ejemplo, en mi caso con Swift, ¿como debería hacer un formulario, usando un tableview con las preguntas en cada celda o un scrollview? Las 2 formas son correctas, pero hay muchas opiniones a favor y encontrar de cada una. Sobre las respuestas que den, pues yo tomaría la opción que mas me haya convencido

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas/respuestas basadas en opiniones no ayudan al sitio. Por ende, no pueden ser publicadas aquí.

Comment: Hasta que no haya un sitio orientado a discusión en español en la familia de StackExchange, me temo que no podrás realizar ese tipo de preguntas. Algún día veremos programadores.SE y entonces será cuando sean bienvenidas.

Comment: Otra opcion es usar el chat del sitio y preguntar ahi, donde se aceptan todo tipo de preguntas que no se aceptan en el sitio.

Comment: @jachguate ni aún así: el sitio (ahora llamado Ingeniería de Software) ya no admite preguntas abiertas de ese tipo.

Answer (score 6):

Existe valor en ese tipo de preguntas pero como han comentado mis estimados Luiggi Mendoza y jachguate, no contamos con la estructura para poder publicar y mantener preguntas de este tipo por ahora.  Recordemos que lo que queremos construir aquí es una base de datos de preguntas con respuestas sólidas y precisas.

Preguntas sobre "qué es mejor, X o Y" no pueden ser contestadas de esta manera así que las rechazamos. Espero y te ayude esta respuesta a conocer los motivos detrás de nuestra decisión.  Puedes también acudir a nuestro [centro de ayuda para leer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) más sobre esto.